# node/jade - display JSON item without knowing the keys beforehand

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

I am building an app using node and the jade template engine.
For some of my pages I'd like to display some JSON items passed by my server:

```
            res.render('index', {
                items: myJSONitems
            });
```

My problem is that I don't know the keys of my item beforehand. How can I display all the fields of my JSONs?

I have thought of using something like this but I don't know how to use it in Jade:

```
        var itemKeys = [];
        if (items.length > 0) itemKeys = Object.keys(items[0].data);

        res.render('index', {
            items: items, item_keys: itemKeys
        });
```

Comment: http://jade-lang.com/reference/#iteration tells you how to iterate over an object using `each value, key in obj`

Comment: thanks a lot, feel free to answer so I can validate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over an object while retrieving both keys and values in Jade using the following syntax:

```
each value, key in obj
  h4=key
  p=value
```

See **[the documentation on iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)** in Jade as well.